# Should Uniform Buffer Objects be used over glUniform when uniform block size is small?

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

I've recently replaced all usage of `glUniform()` in my code to instead use Uniform Buffer Objects (UBO) to better organize my object rendering code.  However, my performance has sharply plummeted as the number of objects drawn increases (an object in my case is anything with it's own offset into a UBO; only one UBO is shared between everything that uses the same shader program).

I think this may be because my objects actually use very little uniform data, sometimes as little as one `vec4`, while a UBO requires each offset be in multiples of `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT` which can be rather large.

I understood UBO to be a strict upgrade to using `glUniform()`, am I mistaken?  Should I have a `glUniform()` path for these simple objects, or is there a necessary step to using UBOs effectively with many different simple objects that I haven't taken?

My scene is mostly quads, with very few objects using more than 4 verts, 6 indices.  Some of these quads have large uniform blocks while most have very simple ones, maybe one or two `vec4`.

(For now, I've gotten around this problem by embedding this object data into the vertices, though it definitely *feels* wrong to do it this way.)

Comment: I is not clear what eaxctly you are doing, and what is the bottleneck performance-wise. Also "while a UBO requires each offset be in multiples of `GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER_OFFSET_ALIGNMENT`": So you re-bind a different UBO range before drawing each object?

Comment: @derhass - yeah, the UBO is uploaded in one big chunk for all objects before drawing, and `glBindBufferRange(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, ...)` is used before drawing every object.  Is that um, not how to use them?

Comment: Well, you can use them that way. It doesn't even have to be an issue. I probably wouldn't do it that way, but OTOH, I also don't know your exact scenario.

Comment: @derhass - I added what I'm rendering to the question (second to last paragraph)

Comment: "My scene is mostly quads, with very few objects using more than 4 verts, 6 indices. Some of these quads have large uniform blocks while most have very simple ones, maybe one or two vec4." Havbing a draw call for 4 to 6 vertices will result in an insanely low usage of the gpu ressources. You might need to re-think how you draw your stuff. The fact that the amount of uniform data per object varies, but you use the same shader for all is a bit confusing. What kind of uniform data do you even need per object?

Comment: @derhass - apologies, I reworded that, there are multiple shaders, but one UBO per shader.  I try to batch quads with the same uniforms into a single call, but I can't do this with translucent objects and I have a lot of them unfortunately.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208274/discussion-between-derhass-and-anne-quinn).